# Where is NewSession and other events documented?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am testing out the [Alexa Skills Kit for Nodejs](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs) currently.

Under [Skill State Management](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#skill-state-management), there are `NewSession` and `Unhandled` events.

However, I am going through the documentation and I cannot find these events or Intents anywhere. Are these custom events or obsolete ones?

Answer (score 0):

`Unhandled`: this intent is called when an intent is invoked which is not handled by your handlers.

`NewSession`: this intent is called when a new session is created. This happens for example when the skill gets launched.

These events are described (as far as I can see) in the nodejs skills kit: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#skill-state-management